# append("a") in y label of d3 graph, effect image downlaod function in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, visualization, bigdata

I customised D3 graph by adding **image download** button and addition of **hyperlink on y axis labels**. Both works very well when I use one of them at single time.

After introducing both in single page,image download button does not work in Firefox and safari. However, it works fine in chrome.

What could be the possible reason?

```
 [link for code][1]
```

Comment: here is the link for code  [ JS fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/adwL21n1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
g.append(
  $("a")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+data[j]['name'])
  .attr('target', '_blank')
  .append(
     $("span")
    .attr("y", j*40+25)
    .attr("x",-200)
    .attr("class","label")
    .text(modify(data[j]['labname'],30,18,"50"))                         
    .style("fill", function(d) { return Set3[color][color2]; }
  )
);
```

append takes a jquery element

EDIT: i think "text" has to be $('span') ?

Comment: your solution didn't work for graph, I tried above but it's not displaying data in graph.

Comment: what is the result of `modify(data[j]['labname'],30,18,"50")`?

Comment: Text, (it's function for trimming the y label text).

Comment: pls have a look on edited code, there was a append("text") what can't work